# Folder names and file names text wrapping in wrong position

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filenames, files-folders

File names and folder names on windows 10 - the text wraps down to the next line and it is visually distracting and, frankly, horrible to read.

How do I stop the text from wrapping? Letters of the same word should not push down to a second line. or at least how to set windows to wrap lonf file name only between words

What I see:

```
Folde
r Na
me
```

What I want:

```
Folder
Name
```

or

```
Folder Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use big icons to prevent, or at least improve, text wrapping.

[image: Text wrapping based on icon size]

To view in real-time the effect of changing icon size, click on the desktop, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and rotate the mouse scroll-wheel. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> occasionally to refresh the screen, because, on occasion, changes might not be immediately visible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but enlarging the icon size did not resolve the problem. Your solution appears to address lengthy folder names, whereas my concern is words breaking and wrapping at a certain character limit in each line.